# Texture Debug for Rasterizer

Tags: c++

I got an assignment at university to make a Rasterizer, I've come this far by making my own math library and all necessary parts, but the results are not perfect

[Cat in rasterizer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g1Bgf.png)

I've tested to mix up the colors a bit and the mesh is whole, no empty areas on it, but I think it's something with the texture, can somebody hint or tell me how to get a clear and complete texture cover?

```
void Rasterizer::scanline(const Scanline &scan)
{    
    int diffX = scan.xEnd - scan.xBegin;

    if (diffX == 0)
    {
        return;
    }

    for (int x = scan.xBegin; x <= scan.xEnd; x++)
    {
        float u, v, w;
        barycentric(vector2D(x, scan.Y), vector2D(vertexOne.vecOrigin[0], 
        vertexOne.vecOrigin[1]), vector2D(vertexTwo.vecOrigin[0], 
        vertexTwo.vecOrigin[1]), vector2D(vertexThree.vecOrigin[0], 
        vertexThree.vecOrigin[1]), u, v, w);
        float corrW = (u * wOne + v * wTwo + w * wThree);
        float zPixel = ((vertexOne.vecOrigin[2] * u) + (vertexTwo.vecOrigin[2] * v) + (vertexThree.vecOrigin[2] * w));

        int index = (scan.Y * width + x);

        if (index < 0 || index >= (width * height))
        {
            continue;
        }

        if (zDepth[index] > zPixel)
        {
            continue;
        }

        zDepth[index] = zPixel;

        vector2D texture = ((uvOne * u) * wOne + (uvTwo * v) * wTwo + (uvThree * w) * wThree) / corrW;
        vector3D normal = ((normOne * u) * wOne + (normTwo * v) * wTwo + (normThree * w) * wThree) / corrW;
        vector3D diff = ((diffColorOne * u) * wOne + (diffColorTwo * v) * wTwo + (diffColorThree * w) * wThree) / corrW;

        PixelColor col = fragments({ texture.vecOrigin[0], 1 - texture.vecOrigin[1] }, normal, image, this->w, this->h, n);

        col.r = std::min((col.r * diff.vecOrigin[0]), 255.0f);
        col.g = std::min((col.g * diff.vecOrigin[1]), 255.0f);
        col.b = std::min((col.b * diff.vecOrigin[2]), 255.0f);

        if ((scan.Y * width + x) < 0)
        {
            continue;
        }
        else if ((scan.Y * width + x) >= width * height)
        {
            continue;
        }   

        if (x > 0 && x < width)
        {
            this->pixels[index] = col;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: use a simpler image that triggers the behavior (e.g. 4x4), derive expected output and print the living shit out of every step in your algorithm. tell us what you find.

Comment: Sorry for late reply, I tried changing my texture to a 10x10 and it still appears the same way

Comment: Hi again! I've been busy with other assignments and a game project. I tried with a box and a 10x10 texture, but only the corner of the box is textured, any suggestions?